# Logging database updates and other events in php/mysql application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, events, logging

I need to be able to determine what database *fields* were changed in a mysql update and then log that change to another db table to eventually display to the user.

This application is for a system that tracks customer orders. It's developed in CodeIgniter, but I don't think that's necessarily relevant unless CI has some built-in library that could be helpful.

For example, here is where the database update occurs:

```
$this->db->update("orders",$this->input->post());
```

I can easily follow this up with an `insert` on the "events" table that says something like "Order Updated", but I have no way to determine *what* part of the Order was actually updated. I would like to be able to instead log something like "Order Status Updated" or "Order Quantity Updated".

How can I determine which db fields were changed in the mysql `update`? The answer doesn't have to be in CodeIgniter...raw php/mysql is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [log mysql updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666638/log-mysql-updates)